# Local administrator privilege is required to update the Farm Administrators' group

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, upgrade, central-administration, farm-setup

I perform an upgrade of SP from WSS SP2 to SPF 2010 SP1.

In WSS SP2, I was able to update the farm administrators. In SPF 2010 SP1, I keep receicing the following in the ULS logs:

> Local administrator privilege is required to update the Farm
>   Administrators' group.

- I have tried multiple accounts. All with the same error message.
- I have also ran the updatefarmcredentials command. Still same error.

[image]

**Update:**

I was able to resolve this issue after running the SP Products Configuration Wizard several times.

Also, currently MS does not support installing SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2012. These issues I am noticing could be the result of unsupported environment.

Update: MS is now saying the installation of SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2012 will be supported once SP 2010 SP2 is released. [Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2724471)

Comment: It' also helpful **[Local administrator privilege is required to update the Farm Administrators’ group within Central Administration in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/local-administrator-privilege-is-required-to-update-the-farm-administrators-group-within-central-admnistration-in-sharepoint/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem when running IE on the server and opening the Central Admin URL.  Went to all Programs/Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products/SharePoint 2010 Central Administration and ran that as an Administrator and had no problems adding users.

I was also able to add users when I used a *workstation* to add users via the URL.

Answer (score 0):

SP2013 and 2012 Server: 
I have noticed that if I start CA via browser, it won't give me add Farm Administrators with the error:Local administrator privilege is required to update the Farm Administrators' group. Even though I use a farm account.
To resolve the issue make sure that you start Central Administration from start menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to add a Farm Admin to a new SharePoint Server 2010 Trial Version on Windows 2008r2. Without going too far down the avenues suggested above, I found a PowerShell script over [here](http://www.sharepoint-reference.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=a2aeeaff-2a1e-4279-adb2-f4437035a0f2&ID=12&Web=b1fee670-5c0b-4a4a-b607-9fa1ca42d2ca) that does the heavy lifting, reproduced below. I ran this from a SharePoint 2010 Management Shell `run as administrator` (may not be necessary to run with elevated permissions).

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

# Creates a new Farm Administrator
$newFarmAdministrator = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please provide the name of the new Farm Administrator in the form of DOMAIN\Username'

$caWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | where-object {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint Central Administration v4"}
$caSite = $caWebApp.Sites[0]
$caWeb = $caSite.RootWeb

$farmAdministrators = $caWeb.SiteGroups["Farm Administrators"]
$farmAdministrators.AddUser($newFarmAdministrator, "", $newFarmAdministrator, "Configured via PowerShell")

$caWeb.Dispose()
$caSite.Dispose()

$caDB = Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication $caWebApp
Add-SPShellAdmin -Database $caDB -Username $newFarmAdministrator
```